# Why is the horizontal space not defined uniquely in a fiber bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry

So I have been told that the vertical space in a fiber bundle is defined uniquely but there is no unique choice for a horizontal space. At first I decided to give myself some time to think about this, but I must confess after several weeks I still don't understand why!
If $\pi: P \to M$ is a fiber bundle, the vertical space at $q\in P$ is defined as:
$$V_q(P)= \ker(\pi_*)$$
and $H_q(P)$ is defined to be the complement vector space of $V_q(P)$ at $q$ in $T_q(P)$. Why is that not defined uniquely? At least when the dimension is finite, the complement space should be unique in the case of vector spaces, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define the horizontal space, one must use a connection form. The vertical space is defined canonically as the tangent space to the fibres.But basic linear algebra says that a subvector space may have more than one complement

Comment: Consider the vector space generated by u and v, the line  (v+cu) is a complement of (u) for any real c

Comment: @H.Z. they are isomorphic, but all this means is that they have the same dimension! One would like a very concrete understanding of horizontality - i.e. to be able to say whether or not a given direction in $P$ is horizontal. Knowing the isomorphism class of horizontal space does not give us this.

Comment: @H.Z.: you don't have a unique *basis* for $V_q(P)$, but the *space* itself is uniquely defined.

Comment: @H.Z.: Consider this situation in $\mathbb R^3$: you are given a vector $v$ and want to consider the plane orthogonal to it. This plane is a well-defined subspace (there is a unique plane orthogonal to any non-zero vector), but there is no natural choice of basis for it. I don't think bases are a useful conceptual tool here - it's better to have a more geometric picture in mind. From a geometric point of view, the reason we can't take a distinguished complement is that we don't have a distinguished inner product to take the complement with respect to.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: So, when we say that a vector space is defined uniquely, we mean that it is defined uniquely as a "set". Right?

Comment: @H.Z.: correct.